# On the defninition of white noise, a question concerning the notes on SPDE's from Walsh

Tags: stochastic-calculus, stochastic-pde

In page 5  from the notes ["An introduction to SPDE's"](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/BFb0074917) from Walsh, one reads:

[image]

According to this definition $W(\emptyset) $ is not $0$. Isn't this a typo on the notes, I mean, shouldn't it be

$$W(A \cup B) = W(A) + W(B)?$$

Comment: Of course. $ $ $ $

Comment: This A definition of white noise rather than THE definition. You can also see it as a random Schwartz distribution $W$ acting on test functions which here are indicators of sets like $A$, $B$, etc. The formula with the union is just linearity.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that is a typo. You are correct that that is a typo.